# Android XML referencing via dollar sign vs dot sign

Tags: android, android-xml

Why is Android using `$` sign to reference **nested** class, instead of standard `.` sign.  As far as I know, in Java `$` is related to **inner** class context (in stacktrace).

```
<view class="path.to.Outer$Nested" ... />
```

In data-binding `.` sign is being used to reference **nested** class as expected:

```
<variable name="..." type="path.to.Outer.Nested" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the inner class is not static.

```
class Parent {

  class Child {
  }
}
```

would result in `Parent$Child` while

```
class Parent {

  static class Child {
  }
}
```

would be referenced as `Parent.Child`.

Comment: So it is possible to use inner class in XML (`inner = public class Outer{ public class ClassName{}}, nested = public class Outer{public static class ClassName{}}`)? I've read somewhere that view defined in outer class should always be static, which seems legit. Without static, inflater would require to have reference on outer class insteance in order to instantiate this inner class.

Comment: Don't know about databinding to be honest with you. Added an example on the answer to help make it clearer

Comment: But how it is even possible to use inner view (see my comment)? When I saw Parent$Child view, it was always static child i. e. nested class.